# Synchronous Http Request and Response in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any way to make synchronous request to web server in windows phone 8 .

I am requesting a particular URL  from a periodic task but this request is asynchronous but I want to make a synchronous request which is the requirement. 
Can any one give me idea how to achieve this . Please put some code I am completely new to windows phone 8 development

Comment: That's a bad idea as you could be waiting a very long time - 10s of seconds in some cases which is potentially longer than the periodic task allows. In that case the OS will kill your periodic task and if this happens twice your task won't be re-run ever again.

Comment: But the requirement is that ..from background periodic task I have to request an 4 url periodically and one after another . Result received from one url will be used for further processing and on the basis of that result I am requesting another url and so on . So in case of asynchronous request I can't achieve this. So what should I do in that case

Comment: Just because a call is asynchronous doesn't make it (measurably) slower!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make synchronous requests in WP, but you can make an asynchronous call from your background agent. Just make sure you don't call `NotifyComplete` until after you've processed everything.

(To be honest, if you're developing for WP8 and not using `async/await` you're making it difficult for yourself)